# Keyboard not showing uitextfield in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Here is the code to show.

```
UIViewController* viewControoler = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
textfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,280,90)]; 
textfield.placeholder = @"word";
textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
textfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textfield.delegate = self;
textfield.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[textfield becomeFirstResponder];
[viewControoler.view addSubview:textfield];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView] addSubview:viewControoler.view];
```

It is running well. But textfield is not editable because keyboard is not coming when I am clicking on uitextfiled.

Answer (score 1):

Remove UIViewController,directly add on OpenGLView,

```
textfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,280,90)]; 
textfield.placeholder = @"word";
textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
textfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textfield.delegate = self;
textfield.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[textfield becomeFirstResponder];

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView] addSubview:textfield;
```